# azure image blob is prompting download option

Tags: php, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

okay i someone find out how to upload blobs in container of using php on azure, but when even i view the image with plain url like `https://my.blob.url.net/my_image_folder/my_image_name.jpg` the browser prompts to download the image, instead of viewing the image, like normal image is viewed on browser, here is the code i'm using while uploading

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
    $connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=account_name;AccountKey=my_key_value';
    $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
    $content = fopen('folder/image.jpg','r');
    $blob_name = 'image_name.jpg';
    try
    {
        $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("container_name", $blob_name, $content);
    }
    catch(ServiceException $e)
    {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    }
```

this code is working fine, but when accessing the url, it prompts download option, which means i cannot use for `img` html tag

Comment: Did you get it working for PHP. Any samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the blob's content type to an appropriate mime type. The following is a snippet in C# that shows how this can be done:

```
entryData.DestinationBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
entryData.DestinationBlob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: Any PHP example for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

We need to set its property Content type through Blob Options class.

PHP :

```
namespace - use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CreateBlobOptions;

//use code where you are creating blob
$opts = new CreateBlobOptions();

//$opts->setCacheControl('test');
$opts->setContentEncoding('UTF-8');
$opts->setContentLanguage('en-us');

//$opts->setContentLength(512);
$opts->setContentMD5(null);
$opts->setContentType($mimeType);
$blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob($containerName, $indexFile, $content,$opts);
```

**$mimeType**  is Type of your file text/html, text/pdf. It will work in git. 
**package :** "microsoft/windowsazure": "^0.5"